# Convert the timestamp into ("MMM DD, HH:mm") format. JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date returned as a timestamp from the the server response and I want to convert it to `("MMM DD, HH:mm")` format using the `toUTCString()`. so far I have this:

```
date = new Date(1555649122787).toUTCString()
```

o/p:
`"Mon, 22 Apr 2019 23:00:32 GMT"`, however I want the o/p in this format:

`Apr 22, 23:00`. Unfortunately for my project I'm unable to use moment.js as a library. any other better ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Marco answering Intl.DateTimeFormat is the best way, but he forgot to mention that we can remove the elements of dates that we do not want

```js
dateC = new Date(1555649122787);

B_Options = {
  month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' 
};

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', B_Options).format(dateC) );
```

Comment: There are already many duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    return `${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()}, ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
}
date = new Date(1555649122787)
console.log(formatDate(date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Using_options), it's ECMA compatible and has major support:

```
// sometimes even the US needs 24-hour time
options = {
 year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
 hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
 hour12: false,
 timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' 
};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date));
// → "12/19/2012, 19:00:00"
```

You just have to play around to get what you want.